# Korn's inequality implies existence of skew symmetric $w$ such that $\|df-w\|_{L^2}\leq C'\|\mathrm{Sym}\, df\|_{L^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be open and connected and let $f\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$. 
Then Korn's inequality tells us that there exists $C>0$ such that
$$\|f\|_{W^{1,2}}^2\leq C(\|f\|_{L^2}^2+\|\mathrm{Sym}\, df\|_{L^2}^2),
$$
where $(\mathrm{Sym}\, df)_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_i f^j+\partial_j f^i)$.

How does it follow that there exists a (constant) skew-symmetric matrix $w$ (which may depend of $f$) such that
$$\|df-w\|_{L^2}\leq C'\|\mathrm{Sym}\, df\|_{L^2}?$$

I thought about decomposing $f$ into its symmetric and skew-symmetric parts, namely
$f=\mathrm{Sym}\, df+w$,
where $w=\frac{1}{2}(df-df^T)$.
But then I realized that $w$ has to be a constant matrix, so that doesn't really help.